# TextInputLayout - How to decrease the spacing between the hint (no text & focus mode) to the bottom line

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using TextInputLayout to create some layout.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/cvvContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:hint="CVV Number"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

However - I'm not sure how to decrease the spacing between the hint and the bottom border (in the state where the hint is showing because of no text inserted & edit text has no focus):

[image]

I tried to change the padding, the margin, etc...
but none of them works

Answer (score 0):

I played around and this is what i figure out that could meet your need

in `TextInputLayout` set space as `hint` (just copy from here)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cvvContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:hint=" "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:hint="CVV Number"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In the code,

```
TextInputEditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        TextInputLayout cvvContainer = findViewById(R.id.cvvContainer);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() == 0){
                    cvvContainer.setHint("");
                }else{
                    cvvContainer.setHint("CVV NUMBER");
                }
            }
        });
```